# How to add glitter effect in 3D render

Tags: 3d-view, 3d-manipulator

How do you get a glittering effect when navigating inside a 3D-view as shown here [SketchFab Post](https://skfb.ly/6qtKq) ?   As you can see, for some reason the particles around her appear when in motion & almost disappear when stopped. I am just looking for the basics, don't need a highly detailed description.

Comment: you need glittering material? or

Comment: There are particles that get brighter during motion and all but disappear when the 3D-view is at rest.  Giving it a Japanime magic effect.

Comment: Those particles only appear brigther at movement, because the render has not anti aliased them at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy,

- Go to the compositor
- Make sure you check use nodes
- Add a glare node in between "render layers" and "composite"
- Set it to "fog glow" and try various settings till you get desired effect(s)
- "Threshold" controls pretty much how much glow there is
- The lower it is the more glow
- "Size" controls how blurry is the glow
- I normally use only those two settings

Voila !!! Magic lights.